# GSuite service account auth revocation does not stop watch (pub/sub)

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workspace, service-accounts

In order to get notified about changes to the inbox, I create a [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request) with my service account that is authorized by the GSuite admin. This works just fine.

The problem is, when the GSuite admin revokes the authorization to my service account (its like pulling the rug out), I still continue to get the notifications. This is not useful for me since I can't really do anything with those notifications as I no longer have access to the mailbox.

So I have 2 questions -

1. Shouldn't the watch automatically stop if the admin revokes the access to the service account that created the watch?
2. Is there any other way for me to stop receiving the notifications when the access is revoked.

Thanks.

Comment: As you have stated that you keep getting notifications, i think question number one and two should be asked of Google and their support forums.   All we can tell you is that yes you keep getting notifications.  We cant answer should or shouldn't for google.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191602%2B

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch) this automatically will stop sending updates to your account, how many days ago did you start **watch** request?

Comment: Yep, it will eventually stop if I do not refresh the watch. But ideally it should stop immediately given that the authorization to the service account was revoked. 

As an admin, if I do not authorize a service account anymore, why should it keep getting notifications about changes to my account.

I will take this up with Google, thanks to @DaImTo for the issue tracker link.

Comment: Aside from the Google Issue Tracker how you revoked the service account access? Were you impersonating a user through the service account? By revoke you mean delete the service account?